# Running a JQuery function on page load

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am trying to run some jquery on page load but it's now working. It's checking to see if a link is already saved and if so set a table to that. Is this even possible because it should be running against every div with an img class?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img a").live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
        var item=$(this).attr( 'href' );
        var action="check";
        jqxhr = $.post("webservice.php", { action: action, color: item }, function(data) {
            var result=data.result;
            if (result="saved") {
                $("span", this).html("Saved");
                $(this).attr("href","saved");
            }

        }, "json")
        .error(function() {         
            alert("error: unable to contact web service"); 
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
                            <td>
                                <div class="img" style="background:#f8d3cf;">
                                    <a href="f8d3cf" rev="1" class="link">
                                        <span>Click to Save</span>
                                        <em>Saved</em>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="popup">
                                        <div class="holder">
                                            <div class="popup-img" style="background:#f8d3cf;"></div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <h3>Desert Warmth</h3>
                                                <strong class="num">70YR 56/190 <span>A0542</span></strong>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. `.on()` is the preferred function.

Comment: `if (result="saved") ` is assignment not equality

Comment: @dnagirl If a function is deprecated doesnt affect the way it works. So its not relevant.

Comment: no I am using normal jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: @dnagirl .on or .live it does the same thing. I'm under the impression that we can't do what I want do here.

Comment: Pageshow if im not mistaken is a jquery mobile function

Comment: @Jonathan Cruz: it may not affect whether his code works now. But it will eventually. Having to weed out deprecated functions is not one of my favourite code-maintenance tasks so I like to save others that sort of work when I can.

Comment: @dnagirl it will if the deprecated function/method/class is removed but i mean that its not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @JonathanCruz: yes I understand what you meant and your comment would be important if I were suggesting that `.live()` was the problem. I was not.

Comment: @dnagirl i meant that you shouldnt suggest as the purpose is to get an answer to the problem. Suggestions only confuse if they dont directly relate to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned pageshow is a qmobile event and onpageshow is html5 which isn't supported in all browsers. The answer is to use 'window.onload= function() {};' Anything in that window.onload will process at page load. Here's how I used window.onload. The first ajax call loads the cart_id from the session or creates one if need be. On completion of the ajax call the application that populates the item in the shopping cart is called.

```
window.onload = function() {
    $j(".cartid").each(function() {
        var self = $j(this);

        jqxhr = $j.post("mycartid.php", function(data) {
            self.html(data.cart_id);
        }, "json").complete(function() {

            $j("#cartitems").each(function() {
                var self = $j(this);
                jqxhr = $j.post("printitems.php", function(data) {
                    //var result=data.result;
                    self.html(data);
                }, "html");

            });
        });
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

On your last line '));' should be '});

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img a").live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
        var item=$(this).attr( 'href' );
        var action="check";
        jqxhr = $.post("webservice.php", { action: action, color: item }, function(data) {
            var result=data.result;
            if (result="saved") {
                $("span", this).html("Saved");
                $(this).attr("href","saved");
            }

        }, "json")
        .error(function() {         
            alert("error: unable to contact web service"); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help though fixing the typo didn't solve the problem.